# How to revert back or transform one-hot encoded columns and display feature importance of original features and not in encoded form?

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

Using `RandomForestClassifier`, this is the current important feature list:

```
bill_length          0.367075
flipper_length_mm    0.196314
bill_depth           0.153329
body_mass_g          0.152304
Island_Biscoe        0.079014
Island_Dream         0.027223
Island_Torgersen     0.024742
```

Assuming there are two encoded features: `bill` (`bill_length`, `bill_depth`) and `Island` (`Island_Biscoe`, `Island_Dream`, `Island_Torgersen`), how can I get the feature importance list in the following format instead?

```
bill                 0.520404
flipper_length_mm    0.196314
body_mass_g          0.152304
Island               0.130379
```

Thanks

Comment: To my understanding, you can't. But I follow the question now in case there is indeed a method how to do this.